# texture baking is having a problem

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

[image]

so I have procedural texture that I made in blender and wanted to baked it and add some additional details in substance but whenever I bake it it gives me this result. I don't know what to do I hope anyone can help me

Comment: "*Whenever I bake it it gives me this result*" What results were you expecting, what was it supposed to look like? What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: helloo i dont know if you will get a notification on this i dont know how to mention users in this website hahahaha, but what i expect was to have a skin with all the added procedural texture, and i did fixed it tho, the direct and indirect light is getting in the way of baking, if you have a suggestion on that plst let me know